# Inverse selection in hunspell

Tags: hunspell

Is there any tag in hunspell to declare the current word as wrong but all it's tags to be valid?

In the following example, how do I declare the original word "party" as a wrong word while it's plural form "parties" to be correct?

```
party/S

SFX S Y 9
SFX S y ies [^aeiou]y
SFX S 0 s [aeiou]y
SFX S 0 es [sxz]
SFX S 0 es [cs]h
SFX S 0 s [^cs]h
SFX S 0 s [ae]u
SFX S 0 x [ae]u
SFX S 0 s [^ae]u
SFX S 0 s [^hsuxyz]
```

---

I can use No-suggest flag. But that will accept the "party" word as correct one and will not underline it as wrong. The only difference is that the word will not be suggested. I want to treat it as wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared a new tag

```
NEEDAFFIX x
```

and then used it in the dictionary...

> party/Sx